# Resnet50 predicts all the images to be of the same class

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet, transfer-learning

I have experimented with a number of models available in Keras on my dataset. It is a 10-class image classification problem. I have tried training from scratch, fine-tuning the whole network and transfer learning with each architecture. Most of them perform quite well on my dataset, except transfer learning with Resnet50. Here is the model I am using:

```python
model = applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)
predictions = Dense(output_dim=10, activation="softmax")(x)

model_final = Model(input=model.input, output=predictions)
```

All the images have already been resized to (224 x 224) pixel size. I have tried adam optimizer with various learning rates and batch sizes like:

```python
lr=0.00001, batch=64
lr=0.00005, batch=256
lr=0.001, batch=256
lr=0.001, batch=128
lr=0.001, batch=64
lr=0.001, batch=32
lr=0.0001, batch=64
lr=0.0001, batch=32    
lr=0.0001, batch=128
```

But still the model predicts all the images to be of the same class, and to be specific, the class which contains 26% of all the images. While training, the training loss reduces and the validation loss seems to increase. The training accuracy is above 95% at the end of training, but the validation accuracy is stuck at 26%. When the same model (Resnet50) is trained from scratch or fine-tuned, this problem doesn't exist. The models with no skip connection (such as InceptionV3, Xception, VGG16) show good performance all the time, whether training from scratch, fine-tuning or transfer learning is used. The other models using skip connections (InceptionResnetV2, DenseNet) don't predict all the images to be of the same class when transfer learning is used, but the accuracy is a bit lower compared to "no skip connection" models. Again, these models (InceptionResnetV2, DenseNet) show good performance when training from scratch or fine-tuning is used.

So my question is,

> Is there something with the skip connection which is hurting the performance of the model when transfer learning is used?

I am using Keras with tensorflow backend.

Comment: how your model was performing while training? is training loss reducing?

Comment: While training, the training loss reduces and the validation loss seems to increase. The training accuracy is above 95% at the end of training, but the validation accuracy is stuck at 26%. @SargamModak

Comment: I think you can try adding a Pool layer before `Flatten()`. Also, have you tried changing dimensionality in the last few layers you added? It looks like model is over fitting. Maybe increase the from 128 to 512

Comment: I am now trying changing the number of nodes in the last layers. I will let you know the result. Thanks for pointing this out. @unholy_me

Comment: I have increased the number of nodes to 512 in the last layers, and still the same problem remains. @unholy_me

Comment: Have you tried gradually decreasing them? Like 512 -> 256 -> 128 ->64-> 10?

Comment: I have tried all of them, still the result remains the same @unholy_me

Comment: Last of all try increasing the learning rate to something like 0.05. If that fails, try reducing the number of images in your dominant class.

Comment: Tried both, but the problem of diverging in validation set still persists. Getting confused now. @unholy_me

Comment: I think you might want to raise this question in Keras forums along with link to dataset maybe.

Comment: @PreetomSahaArko I have exactly your problem. Did you find any solution ?